# font-face is not working on https secure server pages

Tags: https, font-face, truetype

@font-face is not working on https secure server pages.
here's my css.

css:

```
h3 {font-family:'Swiss721CondensedRegular'}
```

font-face:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Swiss721CondensedRegular';
src: url('../fonts/swiss721bt-romancondensed-webfont.eot'); src: url('../fonts/swiss721bt-romancondensed-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because there are two `src`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/src#description

> If multiple src descriptors are set, only the last declared rule that is able to load a resource is applied.